# Failed to launch chrome! spawn ...node_modules/puppeteer/.../chrome ENOENT TROUBLESHOOTING when using Puppeteer

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer, headless, google-chrome-headless

I was trying to build a quick lambda that prints a pdf with a specific url, but I get this error: **Failed to launch chrome! spawn ...node_modules/puppeteer/.../chrome ... TROUBLESHOOTING**

Methods mentioned here : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/807#issuecomment-366529860 did not help me.

The code I'm using:

```js
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      executablePath: '../../node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624487/chrome-linux/chrome',
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    });
    try {
      const result = await exports.run(browser);
      callback(null, result);
    } catch (e) {
      callback(e);
    }

    ...
 
    exports.run = async (browser) => {
      // implement here
      // this is sample
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://www.google.com', {
        waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0']
      });
      console.log((await page.content()).slice(0, 500));

      await page.type('#lst-ib', 'aaaaa');
      // avoid to timeout waitForNavigation() after click()
      await Promise.all([
        // avoid to
        // 'Cannot find context with specified id undefined' for localStorage
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.click('[name=btnK]'),
      ]);

      // cookie and localStorage
      await page.setCookie({
        name: 'name',
        value: 'cookieValue'
      });
      console.log(await page.cookies());
      console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('name', 'localStorageValue');
        return localStorage.getItem('name');
      }));
      const result = await page.pdf({
        path: 'hn.pdf',
        format: 'A4'
      });
      console.log(` typeof : ${typeof result}, pdf: ${result}`);
      await page.close();
      return 'done';
    };
```

Comment: actually puppeteer is trying to find chrome.exe but not able to find its problem with extraction of fodler

Answer (score 4):

check this path =>
**\node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium\win32-818858\chrome-win**

you will notice chrome.exe will not exist, now got back one step =>
**\node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium**

you will find zip file "chrome-win" extract it and move it int to =>
**\node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium\win32-818858**

Now you may check it will work.

Comment: You sir, just saved me hours!!!! ❤️